# How to wait for more than 10 minutes a successful deployment on AWS Opsworks?

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, deployment, continuous-deployment, aws-opsworks

I am deploying an application on AWS using `AWS Opsworks`. I have automated the deployment in a script, and I would like to make my task last as long as the deployment has not been finished on `Opsworks`.

I am using the command `deployment-successful` to do it, but it exits `255` after 10 minutes if the deployment is not finished yet. And sometimes our `Opsworks` deployments last longer than than 10 minutes. Is it possible to catch the exit code to relaunch the command in such case?

I have tried this code but it exits directly `255` without relaunching:

```
#!/bin/bash

wait_deploy_output() {
  echo "Waiting for deploy to finish..."

  wait_deploy=$(aws opsworks \
    --profile $AWS_PROFILE \
    --region $AWS_REGION \
    wait deployment-successful \
    --deployment-ids $1)

  wait_status=$?

  [ "$wait_status" = 255 ] && wait_deploy_output $1

  if [ "$wait_status" = 0 ]; then
    echo "Deployed successfully!"
  fi

  exit $wait_status
}

wait_deploy_output $deployment_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Try with the below modified script:-

```
#!/bin/bash

wait_status=0

wait_deploy_output() {
  echo "Waiting for deploy to finish..."

  wait_deploy=$(aws opsworks \
    --profile $AWS_PROFILE \
    --region $AWS_REGION \
    wait deployment-successful \
    --deployment-ids $1)

  wait_status=$?

}

wait_deploy_output $deployment_id

  while true
  do
    if [ $wait_status -eq 255 ]; then
       echo "Deployment not successful"
       echo "Re-deploying it again"
       wait_deploy_output $deployment_id
    elif [ "$wait_status" = 0 ]; then
       echo "Deployed successfully!"
       break
    fi
  done

  exit $wait_status
```